# Curl post with multipart/form-data and boundary php

Tags: php, curl, authentication, web-scraping

I want to create a login from another website using curl, but I got into trouble during the creation.

The script I use as follows:

```
$post_login_client = array("account_number" => 1234123, "pin" => 123123, "submit"=>"");
$headers = array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryijPWqniP0zu0m47e"); 
$fp = fopen("cookie-website.txt", "w");
fclose($fp);
$login = curl_init();
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie-website.txt");
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie-website.txt");
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, "https://secure.website.com/client/login");
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
return curl_exec ($login);
curl_close ($login);
```

Comment: What is the trouble?

Comment: Please tell about problem or any errror message that arise

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take your time to read your question and check if it corresponds to the [help guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). The question current state lacks a bit of information and might get closed as too broad. Please include the errors you had and where did your script fail.

Comment: script above to do login, make me can not enter and enter with invalid login name, all data login is appropriate